# Tela cinza em vídeos

Tags: android, html5-video

Estou tocando vídeos no android (Versões acima da 5 somente) usando um webview junto com a tag `<video>` do html. O vídeo toca perfeitamente e dispara todos os eventos corretamente, porém toda vez que um vídeo vai tocar ele sempre exibi uma imagem de preview parecida com essa (da pra reproduzir abrindo o youtube pelo chrome em seu smartphone) :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Existe alguma maneira elegante de contornar esse problema ?** A unica opção que pensei, porém não testei, foi de antes do vídeo começar a definitivamente tocar (evento de timeupdate diz o tempo do vídeo, logo, se passar de 0.1 segundos eu consigo saber que ele já ta tocando) fazer umas trocas de layer com css botando uma div com background preto na frente, mas parece muita gambiarra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa imagem se chama "poster". Ela serve para mostrar algo antes do vídeo começar a tocar, geralmente aparece quando o vídeo esta sendo carregado.

Eu contornei o problema adicionando no elemento video o seguinte código:

```
<video poster='#' id="video" class="autoAdjust visible"></video>
```

e no css:

```
video {
  background: black;
}
```